# "ValueError: call stack is not deep enough" when calling IPython.embed() method from C

Tags: python, c, api, ipython

I would like to call a function defined in a Python module from the Python C API. For instance, I would like to call `IPython.embed()`. The following C code leads to a run-time error (with Miniconda 3 with IPython installed).

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyObject *ipython = PyImport_ImportModule("IPython");
  if (ipython == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    return 1;
  }
  PyObject *embed = PyUnicode_FromString("embed");
  if (embed == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    return 1;
  }
  PyObject *result = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(ipython, embed);
  if (result == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Error observed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 381, in embed
    frame = sys._getframe(1)
ValueError: call stack is not deep enough
```

However, the code above works fine if I replace `IPython` and `embed` by a reference to a simple `test` module with a mere `hello` function defined in it.

On the other hand, the following code works as intended (i.e., it runs the IPython REPL) but is not as flexible as the code above and is not suitable for my needs.

```
PyRun_SimpleString("\n\
  from IPython import embed\n\
  embed()\n\
");
```

The following code works also as intended, where the code that I have initially given now lives in a callback called with `PyRun_SimpleString`.

```
static PyObject *
callback_f(PyObject *obj, PyObject *args)
{
  PyObject *ipython = PyImport_ImportModule("IPython");
  if (ipython == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
  PyObject *embed = PyUnicode_FromString("embed");
  if (embed == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
  PyObject *result = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(ipython, embed);
  if (result == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
  Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyObject *module = PyImport_AddModule("test");
  if (module == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    return 1;
  }
  PyMethodDef method_def;
  method_def.ml_name = "callback";
  method_def.ml_meth = callback_f;
  method_def.ml_flags = 1;
  method_def.ml_doc = NULL;
  PyObject *callback_obj = PyCFunction_New(&method_def, NULL);
  if (callback_obj == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    return 1;
  }
  if (PyObject_SetAttrString(module, "callback", callback_obj) != 0) {
    PyErr_Print();
    return 1;
  }
  PyRun_SimpleString("\n\
  from test import callback\n\
  callback()\n\
");
}
```

I suppose therefore that `PyRun_SimpleString` performs an initialization related to the stack frame that is necessary to call `IPython.embed()`, but I don't see where it is documented.

Comment: Looking at what `sys._getframe` does, I understand that IPython.embed needs a stack frame of size at least 2 (for `sys._getframe(1)` to succeed), and the only functions that makes the stack frame grow are `PyEval_EvalFrame` and co, that suppose some Python code to be effectively interpreted. So I can’t make something much simpler than the last example I have given (with an interpreted call to `test.callback()`). Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to insert a new frame created with PyFrame_New, but it is outside the documented Python C API.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <frameobject.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyThreadState *tstate = PyThreadState_GET();
  if (tstate == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
  PyObject *main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
  if (main_module == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
  PyObject *main_dict = PyModule_GetDict(main_module);
  if (main_dict == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
  PyCodeObject *code_object = PyCode_NewEmpty("foo.py", "f", 0);
  if (code_object == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
  PyFrameObject *root_frame = PyFrame_New(tstate, code_object, main_dict, main_dict);
  if (root_frame == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
  tstate->frame = root_frame;
  PyObject *ipython = PyImport_ImportModule("IPython");
  if (ipython == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
  PyObject *embed = PyUnicode_FromString("embed");
  if (embed == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
  PyObject *result = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(ipython, embed);
  if (result == NULL) {
    PyErr_Print();
    exit(1);
  }
}
```